# Update dynamically generated tables

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After setting specific conditions and press the inquiry button.
The number of tr from the table that is generated dynamically is 76.
The number of things loaded on the screen is 76, and if you actually scroll,
I think 76 new data will be set based on what you see on the screen.
There are actually hundreds of data to load.

I tried various methods to move scroll, but the data in the table was not updated.

How can I update the data on the table?

table column

1. Date 2) Price 3) EPS 4) PER 5) PBR

[source code]

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='jsSearchButton']")).Click();
wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody")));
IWebElement tbody = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody"));
IList<IWebElement> trs = tbody.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
Log.Normal($"trs Count : {trs.Count}"); // trs Count is 76


for (int row = 1; true; ++row)
{
    //ElementExists function :  if element exist return element else return null
    IWebElement date = ElementExists(driver, $"//*[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{row}]");
    if (date == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        IWebElement date = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{row}]/td[1]"));
        Log.Normal($"date  : {date .Text} {date .GetAttribute("textContent")}");
        ...
        IWebElement PBR= driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{row}]/td[5]"));
        Log.Normal($"PBR : {PBR.Text} {PBR.GetAttribute("textContent")}");

        // Various attempts to move the scroll
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(PBR).Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.End).Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(Keys.Space).Perform();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", PBR);
    }
}
```

Comment: In python we have- `driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,100)")`. Here 100 means 100 pixels. Try to find something similar to this for C#.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I test below code but table is not updated.

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript($"window.scrollTo(0, 100)");
or 
js.ExecuteScript($"window.scrollTo(0, {row*100})");

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @pmadhu
<http://data.krx.co.kr/contents/MDC/MDI/mdiLoader/index.cmd?menuId=MDC0201020502>

1. [조회구분] choose second radio button(개별추이)  2. [종목명] type 005930 and click reading glasses
3. [조회기간] select long enough period
4. click 조회(means search) black button on the top right
5. you can see the table(class="CI-GRID-BODY-TABLE")

Comment: @user2523112 - You should click on the `Close` button at the top of the table to view more entries. Have tried in python programming language, and was able to extract `92` entries. Go through the answer. It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below xpath and was able to find 92 entries - from `2021/10/18` to `2021/06/03`. You should click on `Close` button to view more entries.

```
//div[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]//table/tbody/tr
```

Since I cannot implement this in C# , have provided the program flow with the code(in python).

```
1: Go to url "http://data.krx.co.kr/contents/MDC/MDI/mdiLoader/index.cmd?menuId=MDC0201020502"
2: Manually select the options like "individual trend" and "1 year" and click on "Lookup"
3: Click on "Close" button to be able to view more entries. Xpath used - "//button[contains(@class,'btn_close_tggle')]"
4: Find the table entries with this xpath - "//div[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]//table/tbody/tr"
5: Print the length of entries which outputs "92".
6: Iterate over the entries to extract details in a for loop. Apply scrollIntoView to view all the entries.

This is the code:
driver.get("http://data.krx.co.kr/contents/MDC/MDI/mdiLoader/index.cmd?menuId=MDC0201020502")
time.sleep(20) # to manually select options
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn_close_tggle')]").click()# click on "close" button

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='jsMdiContent']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]//table/tbody/tr") # Find entries
print(len(options))

for i in range(len(options)): # iterate over entries
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",options[i])
    print(options[i].find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]/font").get_attribute("innerText")) # "./td[1]/font" xpath is used to extract the date from that particular "tr", and prints the same.
```

**Output**:

```
92
2021/10/18
2021/10/15
...
2021/06/03
```

Comment: Thanks for answer  
i added code to click  
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='MDCSTAT035_FORM']/div[1]/button")).Click();
It increases the content shown at once, but when you have to show something beyond it, the table is still not updated, so I still can't see anything outside the scope of the added content.